# Offset results of children nodes from N1QL Analytics query

Tags: nosql, couchbase, sql++

N1QL tutorial for Query has example of how to offset results of the children nodes. 
https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/#15

I am trying to write the same query for Couchbase Analytics, but get syntax error.
Goal is to get parent and children starting certain index in children array. For example:

```
SELECT children[2:array_length(children)] 
FROM tutorial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array slicing syntax is not yet supported in Couchbase Analytics (but it will be soon).
Currently, you can use a nested subquery to get the same result

```
SELECT (SELECT VALUE c
        FROM t.children c
        LIMIT array_length(t.children) - 2
        OFFSET 2)
FROM tutorial t
```